# Compile files to original location with Babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a folder structure like the following

```
src
├── a
│   └── test-a.js
└── b
    └── test-b.js
```

I want to use babel to compile the files from `./src`. So If I run the following command, I can get it done.

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/ -d ./dist/
```

This will create compiled files (preserving the tree) into `./dist` directory. However, I need to compile files and keep in the same directory.

For example, The tree then should look like this

```
src
├── a
│   └── test-a.js
│   └── test-a.dist.js
└── b
    └── test-b.js
    └── test-b.dist.js
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This means that any `require` calls like `require('../a/test-a')` in your `.dist` files in your code will be pointing at the original non-`dist` file, which is why this is uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a built-in way to do it with the CLI (I kind of doubt it), but you can script it with the API. Do something like glob in `src/**/*.js`, loop over the pathnames calling `require("babel-core").transform()` on each, then do a replace on the pathname like `replace(/\.js$/, ".dist.js")` and write to the new pathname. There's probably also a way to shell script it to transform to `dist/` with the CLI like you're doing now then rename & move those files into `src/`.